# shutil.copyfileobj method in python copies BOM character also while merging files

Tags: python, file-io, utf-8, utf-16, byte-order-mark

I have list of temp files which are created in utf-16 LE encoding . I need to merge those temp files and the resultant file should be in utf-16 .

What I had done

```
for fd in source_fds_list:
   with open(destination_url, 'ab') as destn_fd:
       shutil.copyfileobj(fd, destn_fd)
   fd.close()
```

It results in more than one BOM appended in the destination file .

### I have few solutions for the above scenario .

- Need to check and remove/skip the BOM character in every temp files
- Creating temporary files in utf-8 format which don't have BOM character and then merge them using copyfileobj

What if we do if the temporary files were written in different encoding style ?

Is there better solution exists  other than manually checking for BOM using file read ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shutil.copyfileobj()` copies **all** data, regardless. A BOM is just data in the file, `shutil` is not and will not be aware of such file-format specific details.

You can easily skip the BOM yourself but leave the bulk of the copying to `shutil.copyfileobj()` still:

```
import codecs

for fd in source_fds_list:
   with open(destination_url, 'ab') as destn_fd:
       with fd:
           start = fd.read(2)
           if start != codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE:
               destn_fd.write(start)
           shutil.copyfileobj(fd, destn_fd)
```

By reading an initial 2 bytes from the source file first, `shutil.copyfileobj()` will continue to read everything else in the file, skipping the BOM. All `shutil.copyfileobj()` does under the hood is call `data = source.read(buffer)` and `destination.write(data)`, anyway.

If you don't know the codecs used for the input files, you are stuck with heuristics. You can test for the various [`codecs` BOM constants](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM) but the possibility of false-positives then arises; a file encoded with a codec other than UTF-* and initial bytes *looking* like a BOM:

```
for fd in source_fds_list:
   with open(destination_url, 'ab') as destn_fd:
       with fd:
           start = fd.read(4)

           if start not in (codecs.BOM_UTF32_LE, codecs.BOM_UTF32_BE):
               if start[:3] != BOM_UTF8:
                   if start[:2] in (codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE, codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE):
                       # UTF-16 BOM, skip 2 bytes
                       start = start[2:]
               else:
                   # UTF-8 BOM, skip 3 bytes
                   start = start[-1]
               # Not a UTF-32 BOM, write read bytes (minus skipped bytes)
               destn_fd.write(start)

           shutil.copyfileobj(fd, destn_fd)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin . I know the above solution . But What if we  don't know the encoding style of the temp files ?

Comment: @Shankar: You'd have to use heuristics. If you don't know the encodings then all you can do is guess. It'll help if the range of codecs is limited; you can test for all `BOM` values in the [`codecs` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM) to detect them, perhaps.

Comment: @Martin Is there any other way we can skip the BOM while copy the file object ?