# How do I combine several files removing BOM using Windows command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have several very large CSV (technically TSV) files that I need to append together. I had used:

```
copy file1.txt + file2.txt + ... + fileN.txt combined.txt
```

but then discovered that each file has a BOM at the start (`ï»¿`) which then appears multiple times in the middle of the file.

However, the files are very big (30-40 million lines each) so I can't open them in NotePad++ and re-save them to remove the BOMs, so need a command-line solution (either cmd or PowerShell), and ideally something that doesn't require downloading extra libraries.

To recap:

- Files are too large to open in e.g. NotePad++, so solution needs to be for command line
- This is on Windows, not *nix

*(in my case N=4, so I could cope with a solution that removes the BOM from an individual file, and so run this for each file first before combining)*

Edit: This may be a possible solution: [Batch script remove BOM (ï»¿) from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272705/batch-script-remove-bom-%C3%AF-from-file) but my knowledge of encodings and PowerShell/batch is so poor that I can't even tell if it's applicable or not!  I don't mind if the combined file is ANSI or UTF-8 (I'm going to load it into a program that can cope with either), as long as it is internally consistent and correct.

Comment: What's the encoding of the files you have?

Comment: I think it's UTF-8 - viewing the results of my `copy`-based attempt in a large file viewer utility that I have, the BOMs appear as `ï»¿` which is apparently what UTF-8 BOM looks like when opened with ANSI encoding - I'm guessing this is what my large file viewer uses and there doesn't seem to be an option to change it. Or maybe ANSI is what `copy` uses... or maybe both? ‍♂️ (my understanding of these things is sadly limited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Your own Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809808/45375) is likely the simplest and best-performing solution.
- **If you happen to have [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) installed**, you can try the following to merge all `file*.txt` into `combined.text` while stripping the UTF-8 BOM from each (syntax is for calling *from PowerShell*):

  ```sh
  bash.exe -c 'for f in file*.txt; do tail -c +4 \"\$f\"; done > combined.txt'
  ```

  - `tail -c +4` strips the first 3 bytes from each file and passes the remaining bytes through. Note that the entire output from a `for` loop can be captured by applying a redirection `>` to the `for` statement as a whole.
  - Note: Neither escaping `"` nor `$` with `\` should be necessary here, but is as of this writing:

    - Calling `bash.exe` with `-c` unexpectedly subjects the command string to *up-front string interpolation*, necessitating escaping; note that the following, seemingly equivalent call via `wsl.exe -e` does *not* exhibit this problem (which is why `$f` isn't escaped as `\$f` here):

      ```sh
       wsl.exe -e bash -c 'for f in file*.txt; do tail -c +4 \"$f\"; done > combined.txt'
      ```
    - Independently, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.2, PowerShell's argument passing to external programs is fundamentally broken with respect to empty arguments and arguments with *embedded* `"` chars., necessitating *manual* `\`-escaping - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

---

As for **native PowerShell solutions**:

- The size of your files likely necessitates **a memory-efficient streaming solution**.
- However, given the *object*-based nature of the PowerShell pipeline, with no raw byte support, this is likely to be prohibitively slow, especially with byte-by-byte processing, where each byte must be converted to and from a .NET `[byte]` object in memory.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for background information.

For the record, here's the PowerShell solution, though it is likely too slow for large files:

```sh
# !! Unfortunately, the syntax for requesting byte-by-byte processing
# !! has changed between Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7+,
$byteStreamParam = 
  if ($IsCoreClr) { @{ AsByteStream = $true } } 
  else            { @{ Encoding = 'Byte' } }

Get-ChildItem -Filter file*.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Get-Content @byteStreamParam | Select-Object -Skip 3
  } |
    Set-Content @byteStreamParam -LiteralPath combined.txt
```

However, **you can significantly improve the performance by using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-ReadCount` parameter** to read the files in *chunks* (arrays of bytes). The larger the chunk size - memory permitting - the more runtime performance will improve:

```sh
$byteStreamParam = 
  if ($IsCoreClr) { @{ AsByteStream = $true } } 
  else            { @{ Encoding = 'Byte' } }

# How many bytes to read at a time.
$chunkSize = 256mb

Get-ChildItem -Filter file*.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    $first = $true
    $_ | Get-Content @byteStreamParam -ReadCount $chunkSize | ForEach-Object {
      if ($first) { $_[3..($_.Count-1)]; $first = $false } 
      else        { $_ }
    }
  } |
    Set-Content @byteStreamParam -LiteralPath combined.txt
```

---

***Text*-based PowerShell solutions**:

Text-based solutions, while slower, have the advantage of **enabling *transcoding***, i.e. transforming files from one character encoding to another, using the `-Encoding` parameter of `Get-Content` and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).

In the simplest case - **if the individual files fit into memory *as a whole*** (which may not work for you), you can use `Get-Content`'s **`-Raw` switch**<sup>[1]</sup> to read a file's content into memory as a *single, multi-line string*, which is *fast*.

While a **line-by-line streaming solution (omitting `-Raw`)** is possible, it comes with **caveats**:

- it will be slow, because PowerShell decorates each line read with metadata, which is both time-consuming and memory-intensive.
- information about the input file's *newline format* (Windows-format CRLF vs. Unix-format LF) is invariably *lost*, including whether a *trailing* newline was present.

Note that `Get-Content` needs no `-Encoding` argument below, because both PowerShell editions directly recognize UTF-8 files with a BOM.

In ***Windows PowerShell***, unfortunately, file-writing cmdlets do *not* support writing UTF-8 files *without BOM* - `-Encoding utf8` invariable creates files *with* BOM, so assistance from .NET APIs is needed:

```sh
# Determine the output file, as a *full path*, because
# .NET's working dir. usually differs from PowerShell's.
$outFile = Join-Path ($PWD | Convert-Path) combined.text

# Create the output file, initially empty.
$null = New-Item -Path $outFile

Get-ChildItem -Filter file*.txt | 
  ForEach-Object {
    # BOM-less UTF-8 is the default.
    [IO.File]::AppendAllText($outFile, ($_ | Get-Content -Raw))
  }
```

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, not only does `-Encoding utf8` now produce BOM-*less* UTF-8 files (you can request *with*-BOM files with `-Encoding utf8bom`), BOM-*less* UTF-8 is now the *consistent default*, so the solution simplifies to:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Filter file*.txt | 
  Get-Content -Raw |
   Set-Content -LiteralPath combined.txt # BOM-less UTF-8 implied.
```

---

<sup>[1] Despite its name, this switch does *not* result in reading raw *bytes*. Instead, it bypasses the default *line by line* reading in favor of reading the entire file content at once, into a single string.</sup>

Comment: This is really helpful, especially explaining the context of the "_object_-based nature of the PowerShell pipeline" in explaining why an efficient solution is hard there.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Tim.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up in the end and did it in Python (stick to what you know, eh?):

```
import shutil

with open("combined.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as wfd:
    for f in my_file_iterator():
        with open(f, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as fd:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
```

replace `my_file_iterator()` with your chosen method or expression for looping over your files, e.g. something based on `pathlib.Path.glob()`

With help from these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21162146/9219425 (`shutil.copyfileobj()` magic)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294156/9219425 (trick with `utf-8` and `utf-8-sig` encoding)